# "An expression of non-boolean type specified" error executing SQL from .Net

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlclient

I am getting this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'likeram'.

I entered "ram" in `txt_name`:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
                @"Data Source=DELL_LAPTOP\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(
                    "SELECT * FROM newproj where name like" + txt_name.Text, con);
SDA.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a space between the `like` and the string concatentation and the quotation mark around the parameter:

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(
               string.Format("SELECT * 
                              FROM newproj 
                              WHERE name like '{0}'" txt_name.Text), con);
```

Though I'd advise you not to use that method as it is prone to SQL injections. Use SQL Parameters instead:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM newproj where name like @text");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("text", txtName.Text);
var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
```

Comment: I think he also misses `' '` arount string variable.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `'` quotes inside the string, but you shouldn't be inserting text into your SQL queries like this anyway, as they're a major SQL-injection risk:

[image]

You also need to make sure that `%` characters are included with the `like` as otherwise it will only find exact matches:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection(@"...")
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    select * 
    from newproj 
    where name like '%' + @text + '%'") // Add % wildcards
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("text", txtName.Text); // Safe from SQL injection
    var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Also note that you should always dispose of your SQL command and connection objects, and that `using` is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You missed space and single qoute in query

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(
                    "SELECT * FROM newproj where name like '" + txt_name.Text+"'", con);
```

you are using 'like' in where condition but you didn't added wild chars, if you want exact match records, no need of 'like' use 'name= '

like below

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(
                        "SELECT * FROM newproj where name = '" + txt_name.Text+"'", con);
```

if you want to search with  name like use below

```
 SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(
                        "SELECT * FROM newproj where name like '%" + txt_name.Text+"%'", con);
```